# HttpRequestException when making http request between Localstack Lambda and docker container

Tags: c#, docker, localstack

I've got two docker containers running as part of a docker-compose file, ContainerA is localstack where I'm running a lambda function which is trying to make a HTTP POST request to ContainerB using the below simplified code:

```
var content = new StringContent("{ "content": "sample" }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await HttpClient.PostAsync("http://ContainerB/Foo", content);
```

Which raises the following exception:

> Request failed - System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known

If I make the same request from the console of Container A this request succeeds e.g.

`curl http://ContainerB/Foo -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ "content": "sample" }"`

As this request succeeds from the console I'm fairly confident that it's not a networking issue between my docker containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localstack lambda's are created in a new Docker container per execution, this continer is outside of the docker-compose stack and therefore it is not a part of the docker-compose default network. See [this](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/381) GitHub issue for more information.

In order to work around this, you must first create an external bridge network within docker:

`docker network create -d bridge MyNetwork`

And then connect each docker container to it within your docker compose file and register this as an external network:

```
services:
  localstack:
    networks:
      - MyNetwork
  ...
  ...

networks:
  MyNetwork:
    external: true
```